# Latency in calls to Google Cloud APIs from Cloud Run instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

When I make the calls from Cloud Run instance to other cloud APIs for some reason there are huge delays in responses.
Everything works within 1 project.
Even from local machine the calls are much faster (couple of secs) - but deployed in the cloud it takes couple of mins for some requests to complete. As I see it is relevant for all APIs (apart from Firestore, Translate and TTS APIs as well). This is not related to cold starts for sure.

Code example (Node JS) and logs are below:

```
console.log('Received the request for stats');
const usersCollection = this.firestore.collection('users')
const snapshot = await this.usersCollection.get();
console.log('Fetched all users from Firestore');
```

[image: Logs from Cloud Run console]

Answer (score 3):

Well after some further investigation I figured out what the problem was.
The thing is that all the operations I perform happen not before the response is sent but after (this is the way chatbot is architectured).
So the flow looks like this:

1. request to do smth - response 200 that the request is accepted
2. all the business logic and work
3. chatbot sends the message with the results

According to the docs the CPU is allocated only during the request processing by default so the only thing I had to change is to enable CPU allocation for background activities: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#background-activity